# Can you use $sample pipeline with Parse Server?

Tags: mongodb, random, aggregation, parse-server

I would like to select random documents from a collection. I know that there is a $sample pipeline for aggregation but I was not able to use it. I tried the following:

```
  var pipeline = { sample: { size: 2 } }
  var query = new Parse.Query("Questions");
  query.aggregate(pipeline)
    .then(function(results) {
      console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
```

It gives the error:

```
{ Error
    at C:\Users\Can\Desktop\Closer\node_modules\parse\lib\node\RESTController.js:320:19
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 1, message: undefined }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try, Add $ before the sample keyword

```
  var pipeline = { $sample: { size: 2 } }
  var query = new Parse.Query("Questions");
  query.aggregate(pipeline)
    .then(function(results) {
      console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I found out $sample is available from MongoDB 3.2+. I was using Back4App and it looks like their version is below 3.2. I have deployed my own Parse Server instance with mLab(version: 3.6.8). The problem is solved.